# Authenticating a user with condition Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I just want to ask how to log-in a user with a certain condition. Currently I'm using this code:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) 
{
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
}
```

with the above code, I'm able to login a user as long as its username and password matched on my db. But now I want to add a condition that I will only accept a user that has a role_id 1 or 2. Role_id is a field in my user table.

How do I do that? Sorry, I'm just starting to learn laravel 4.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the key/value pair you want to validate inside the array you're passing into `Auth::attempt()`. In your case, something like the following would do the job:

```
Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'role_id' => $role)
```

Laravel will then search for the row with the matching `username` and `role_id` and return the first result.

Comment: i tried adding role_id => 1, 1 is the superadmin and im able to login. But I need to accept another role_id which is 2. Should I add another array key role_id again? Sorry

Comment: What do you mean? Are you looking for a way to dynamically specify which `role_id` to use for the authentication?

Comment: I have a user list with their respective role. Currently I have 3 different roles. Values are 1, 2 and 3. In the event that they log-in, a user can only login if their role is either 1 or 2.

Comment: okay, i found a way. `if (Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'), 'role_id'=>1)) || Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'), 'role_id'=>2)))`. Is this okay?

Comment: Yes, however, that'd mean that you'll be issuing 2 queries for the authentication.

Comment: I think you could pass in a closure instead and it should receive an argument which would be the query builder and you can use that object to specify the `role_id`.